# DNS How do I setup Multiple A records pointing to the same sub-domain?

Tags: windows, dns

I have a sub-domain sub1.primary.com that works correctly. Now I need to setup sub2.primary.com and have it point to the same web application as sub1.primary.com. I tried it as a new A record and a new CName however when I try navigating to sub2.primary.com and expect to see sub1.primary.com I see a completely different application that sits on sub7.primary.com.

I have tried the A record solo, the CName solo, both together, and each instance with and without pointer records. I am using a Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6. I tried googling for an answer and couldn't find any information.

> Here is my setup at the moment. I have created a Host (A) record in DNS for sub2.primary.com with an associated pointer record. I have added the sub2.primary.com to host headers of sub1.primary.com. Whenever I navigate to sub2.primary.com it displays sub7.primary.com instead of sub1.primary.com. Which is bizarre because if it were going to default to something I would rather it default to www.primary. com.
>
> I don't know if it matters but the sub1.primary.com is under SSL and so is sub7.primary.com, along with 5 others on a *.primary.com SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

Each subdomain should have an A record pointing to the same IP. I sounds like this is what you tried first -- if that didn't work, I'd suggest making sure that your web server's vhost configuration is sending sub2.primary.com to the right place.

Comment: Just to make sure I removed everything I had done, added the A record and associated pointer, added the record to the web applications vHost and I still get the same result. I also verified that there is no associated record in the vHost of the sub-domain it is pulling up.

Comment: Does the output of `dig +short sub1.primary.com` match the output of `dig +short sub2.primary.com`?

Comment: I used http://www.geektools.com/digtool.php since I don't have a dig tool installed on my server. All of my subdomains come up the same.

Comment: It's possible that your local machine (and/or local DNS server) is caching an old value. Windows has an nslookup command right? If your local DNS queries are returning the same IP for each of the subdomains, then your problem is the web server, not the DNS.

Comment: All of my sub-domains have the same IP address, this is the first time I have tried to have two different A records point to the same web application. All of the rest of the A records point to a single web application. I have 9 different sub-domains and everything is working correctly with them except this dual pointer, I guess it is possible that it will just not work?

Answer (score 0):

When IIS hosts multiple websites on the same IP address, it uses the incoming request URLs to guess which virtual site to send the client to.

In other words: you need to configure your host headers to accept both names for the appropriate web site. Microsoft publishes some good how-to documentation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324287) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx?mfr=true), or [here is a more detailed explanation](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/iis_multiple_websites.htm).